# Spacing in program using stdout

Tags: python, stdout, spacing

I have two files, 'something.txt' 'program.py'

here's my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

## your code here
import sys

line = ""
for n in [line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]:
    sys.stdout.write(n.split()[0]+n.split()[9]+'\n')
```

when running

```
$ more something.txt | python program.py
```

I get

```
199.72.81.556245
unicomp6.unicomp.net3985
199.120.110.214085
burger.letters.com0
199.120.110.214179
burger.letters.com0
burger.letters.com0
163.205.53.1455666
163.205.53.1428219
163.205.53.141204
tiger2.ocs.lsu.edu8677
199.0.2.275866
tornado.umd.edu5494
```

I want a space between 'n.split()[0]' and 'n.split()[9]'

```
199.72.81.55 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net 3985
199.120.110.21 4085
burger.letters.com 0
199.120.110.21 4179
burger.letters.com 0
burger.letters.com 0
163.205.53.145 5666
163.205.53.142 8219
163.205.53.14 1204
tiger2.ocs.lsu.edu 8677
199.0.2.27 5866
tornado.umd.edu 5494
```

but

```
sys.stdout.write(n.split()[0]+' 'n.split()[9]+'\n')
```

or

```
sys.stdout.write(n.split()[0]+" "n.split()[9]+'\n')
```

isn't valid.
Can someone help?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write(n.split()[0]+' '+n.split()[9]+'\n')`

Comment: @Rahul K P *facepalm* thanks

Comment: The [useless use of `more`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) is an antipattern on top of an antipattern. `python whatever <file` is the proper way to pass `file` to a Python script as standard input in pretty much every shell.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah I'm well aware of that, but the instructor wants us to practice using pipes |

Comment: Even so the value of an interactive program like `more` over the more traditional useless `cat` is negative - more complex and expensive for no actual benefit, because you don't and indeed cannot use its features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost there, use this,

```
sys.stdout.write(n.split()[0]+' '+n.split()[9]+'\n')
```